# error running make for bluez 5.49 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluez

I am trying to install bluez 5.49 on ubuntu 14.04 but I get the following error:

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
mivascu@ubuntu:~/bluez-5.49$ make
make --no-print-directory all-am
  CC       lib/bluetooth.lo
./libtool: 1552: ./libtool: preserve_args+= --silent: not found
./libtool: 1564: ./libtool: preserve_args+= --tag CC: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= gcc: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -DHAVE_CONFIG_H: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I.: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I./lib: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/usr/include/glib-2.0: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -g: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -O2: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -MT: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= lib/bluetooth.lo: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -MD: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -MP: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -MF: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= lib/.deps/bluetooth.Tpo: not found
./libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -c: not found
libtool: compile: you must specify a compilation command
libtool: compile: Try `libtool --help --mode=compile' for more information.
make[1]: *** [lib/bluetooth.lo] Error 1
```

I do have build-essential installed and gcc.
  What could be the issue?
  I have came across this https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4102
  but did not understood what is the solution.

Thanks,
    Mihaita

Comment: Looks like you have some environment variables set already. Check `.bashrc` or similar files and try compiling in fresh environment!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have checked the env variables(printenv) and bashrc script and that does not seem to be the case.  Those symbols that you see listed above as "not found" are not env variables

Comment: Have you ran ./configure before running the make command? Have a look at the following link:-
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/general/bluez.html
You want to run the commands in the "Installation of BlueZ" section.